# Why constructor overloading is an example of compile time polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Constructors get executed in run time, but constructor overloading is an example of compile time polymorphism. Why ?

Comment: Because the constructor overload to be executed is chosen at compile time. No different to regular methods.

Comment: It applies to all method overloading. The types of the arguments can be determined at compile-time, unambiguously identifying the method (ctor or otherwise) with the matching signature.

Answer (score 2):

It is compile-time polymorphism because the constructor overload to be executed is chosen at compile time.

This is effectively no different to regular methods, where the overload of a method to be invoked is chosen at compile-time also, although different parts of the language specification describe the behavior.

- [Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3)
- [Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

Answer (score 0):

Compile time polymorphism mean that compiler decide which method to run.

Bytecode will contain reference to specific method/constructor.

In case of runtime polymorphism decision is made while program actually executed.